# What is the probability that a multiple of $864$ is divisible by $1944$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

If a positive integer multiple of $864$ is chosen
randomly, with each multiple having the same probability of being chosen, what
is the probability that it is divisible by $1944$?

Comment: You can randomly choose a multiple of $864$?

Comment: If every one of the infinitely many multiples of 864 has the same probability $p$ of being chosen, then $p$ can only be zero.  So your question doesn't make sense; you cannot randomly choose a multiple in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no uniform distribution on the integers, it's generally taken for granted that we work with a uniform distribution on, say, $\{-N,\dots,N\}$ and let $N\to\infty$. Now, maybe this will help:

$$\rm ad|bd \iff a|b, \quad thus \quad a|bn\iff \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\big\vert\left(\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}n\right)$$

$$\rm \gcd(x,y)=1  \implies(x|yz \iff x|z)$$

This entails $1944|864n \iff 9|4n \iff 9|n $; what's the probability an integer is divisible by $9$?

Comment: It might be worth noting that in this case this probability is basically inherted from the natural uniform distribution on $Z/9Z$